# Can a diver from 10 m. sustain injury hitting the pool bottom?

Tags: injuries, diving

An Olympic diving pool is min 5.03 m deep. A diver from 10 m enters the water in "perfect pencil shape" and maintains this shape in the water without "breaking" the dive.
Can this diver sustain injury from hitting the bottom of the pool with enough speed? Have such injuries occurred? 
If so, why don't they increase pool min depth?

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving) seems to have reliable information:

> Diving from 10 m and maintaining a downward streamlined position results in gliding to a stop at about 4.5 – 5m.